# python pandas: How dropping items in dateframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a huge amount of points in my dateframe, so I would want to drop some of them (ideally keeping the mean values).

e.g. currently I have

```
    date                calltime
0   1491928756414930    4643
1   1491928756419607    166
2   1491928756419790    120
3   1491928756419927    142
4   1491928756420083    121
5   1491928756420217    109
6   1491928756420409    52
7   1491928756420476    105
8   1491928756420605    35
9   1491928756420654    120
10  1491928756420787    105
11  1491928756420907    93
12  1491928756421013    37
13  1491928756421062    112
14  1491928756421187    41
```

Is there any way to drop some amount of items, based on sampling?

To give more details. My problem is number of values for very close intervals e.g. 1491928756421062 and 1491928756421187

So I have a chart like [image]

And instead I wanted to somehow have a mean value for those close intervals. But maybe grouped by a second...

Comment: dateframe has a sample() method, does not it work for you?

Comment: Well.. Sample gives random values. It's not like I am dropping some values

Comment: What kind of sample are you looking for? Do you have a criteria around which you want to drop values?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `sample()`, but as you said it selects randomly. If you want to take sample according to some logic, for instance, only keeping rows whose value is `mean *.9 < value < mean * 1.1`, you can try the following code. Actually, it all depends on your sampling strategy.

As an example, something like this could be done.

test.csv:

```
1491928756414930,4643
1491928756419607,166
1491928756419790,120
1491928756419927,142
1491928756420083,121
1491928756420217,109
1491928756420409,52
1491928756420476,105
1491928756420605,35
1491928756420654,120
1491928756420787,105
1491928756420907,93
1491928756421013,37
1491928756421062,112
1491928756421187,41
```

sampling:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", ",", header=None)
mean = df[1].mean()
my_sample = df[(mean *.90 < df[1]) & (df[1] < mean * 1.10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [**`resample`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.date)).calltime.resample('s').mean()
```

This is a more complete example

```
tidx = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=10000, freq='10ms')
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(calltime=np.random.randint(200, size=len(tidx))), tidx)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(25, 10))
df.plot(ax=axes[0])
df.resample('s').mean().plot(ax=axes[1])

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]